# Swift - iOS 8 Issue with navigation bar elements

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a little problem with my navigation bar. I want to add title and one button at the top of the view. So I added a Navigation Controller and navigation bar to the view. But when I execute the app, title and the button is almost unvisible. And there is no action at button click.
[image]

Anyone knows or got some suggestions why that is happening?

Thanks.